# facebook api: is it possible to post a link inside of the description text?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Usually when you create an event on facebook, text links are automatically transformed to a html-link on save. Today I figured out, that if you do the same using the API, the link is not converted to a clickable representation. It's just plain text. Is this a spam protection "feature", or am I doing something wrong? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that it's a new spam feature.  :)